# Adding arrows to plots using locator() in R

Tags: r, plot, graphics

Is it possible to add arrows using locator? I gave it a try but no luck....

```
plot(1:3)
arrows(x0=locator(1), x1=locator(1),
       y0=locator(1), y1=locator(1), code=1)#single headed arrow
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at what `locator(1)` returns you'll see why this isn't even close to working:

```
> locator(1)
$x
[1] 1.365533

$y
[1] 2.25695
```

So you were passing a list of length two to each argument. I would probably (though this won't be reproducible so I wouldn't really do it in anger in any analysis) approach this via:

```
> locs <- locator(2)
> locs
$x
[1] 1.265845 1.587567

$y
[1] 2.604642 2.267028
```

The add the arrow using the data saved in `locs`:

```
with(locs, arrows(x0=x[1], x1=x[2], y0=y[1], y1= y[2], code=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer not to use locator in this case.
A very quickly drafted alternative could be the following. To be noted is, that you can 
always change the way you devise 'arrow_pos'

```
arrow_pos = as.data.frame(matrix(1:2,2,2))
colnames(arrow_pos)<- c("x","y")
with(arrow_pos, arrows(x0=x[1],x1=x[2], y0=y[1],y1=y[2]))
```

alternatively, you could also do something like this:

```
x_s<-c(1,2)
y_s<-c(1,2)
arrow_pos <- as.data.frame(rbind(x_s,y_s))
```

In which case you could also fill x_s with commands taking data directly from the vector you are plotting.

```
V1 = 1:3
```

as examples you then store these in your   'arrow_pos'

```
length(V1); ceiling(mean(V1)); median(V1)
```